# (python3) what happend to my recursion function?? why it does not return varieable?

Tags: python

```
n, m = map(int, input().split())
if n < m:
    n, m = m, n

def mod(x,y):
    if x % y:
        mod(y, x % y)
    else:
        return y
        #or return(y) or return (y)

print(mod(n, m))
```

I'm try to make recursive function to get greatest common divisor and least common multiple, but the function does not return the variable.

I checked a variable is fine (it's exist well right before `return` function) and if statement is also fine but the `return()` function does nothing but return `None`.

I tried return string (`return "what"`) but it still returns `None`.

Where is my mistake?
And how to make return function returns variable normally?

Comment: Inside mod, you are _calling_ mod but not _returning_ the value.

Answer (score 1):

```py
def mod(x,y):
    if x % y:
        return mod(y, x % y)
    else:
        return y
```

Comment: i edited it! but it is still not working

Comment: It works for me. Try `print(mod(20, 30))` ?

Comment: yep. i tried both enviroment python idle(3.9.9) and vscode. It returns None. (sad emoji)

Comment: https://www.mycompiler.io/view/00QstPl Run this. It prints `10`

Answer (score 0):

You are returing "y" which is a string instead you should

```
 return y
```

which is a variable

Comment: That appears to have been an irrelevant typo.

Comment: eh.... i did edit my code but it still return nothing.